# Android App multiple data to single ListView Row

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am developing a messaging app; all is going well and I am doing some research on how to add data to the ListView once the user receives a new message. From what I have gathered so far, the `notifyDataSetChanged()` function does this. The tutorial I have uses the function below to update data in the ListView.

```
private void addItemsToList() {  
       int randomVal = MIN + (int) (Math.random() * ((MAX - MIN) + 1));  
       mItems.add(String.valueOf(randomVal));  
       mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
  }
```

As you can see, this will update a single value `randomVal` to the ArrayList. In a messaging scenario, the data to be updated includes the message, sender username and time of sending the message.

My question is, will the above function add more than one item to the ListView Row and if not, what modifications should be made to enable it add more than one value to the ListView?

Comment: You have to implement your own adapter: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: use custom listview

Comment: I have read that tutorial but it only addresses updating the ListView with one variable for each row...I want to add atleast 3 variables to a row @bigdestroyer

Comment: Already have a custom listView @kiran

Comment: First, you have to create a custom XML layout for each list item. Then, create a custom adapter (extends BaseAdapter) and in getView method, inflate the xml and bind your list item to the row view item

Comment: Try this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Adapter for List View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Comment: I have a custom view and custom adapter ready and working. All I want to know is how I can add multiple data to my custom view when the user receives a new message. Currently I am using refresh but I don want people to keep on clicking refresh

Comment: @kiran...the tutorial does not address my issue